# highlighting all keywords in one string

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a code as follows:

```
 $replace = preg_replace("/($A)/","<b>$A</b>",$search);
 $output .= '<div>'.$replace.'</div>';                        
 print("$output")
```

1. $A = keywords matching entries in my database
2. $search = a phrase entered for searching

The result I get now is that the phrase highlighting matched keywords are shown with div boxes independently. Here is an example (Assuming that "ABCDE" is the phrase I search, and "AB" and "E" are the matched keywords):

1. **AB**CDE.
2. ABCD**E**.

Is it possible to highlight all matched keywords in a string within one div box? Just like this:

1. **AB**CD**E**.

Comment: keywords are a array or simple chars, or some words coma separated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a replacement for a few elements, use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php) :

```
function makeBold($match) {
    return "<b>" . $match[0] . "</b>";
}

$pattern = "/[ABE]/";
$str = "ABCDE";
$output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, "makeBold", $str);
echo $output;
```